# Как сделать такую рамку в CSS?

Tags: css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли чисто на CSS сделать вот такую обводку блока, которая перерывается и на концах нее кружочки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/760730/233165

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.frame {
  border: 2px solid #00f;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.frame__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.frame__title>span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.frame__title>span:before,
.frame__title>span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -10px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #00f;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.frame__title>span:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -10px;
}

.frame__content {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="frame">
  <legend align="center" class="frame__title">
    <span>Title</span>
  </legend>
  <div class="frame__content">Content</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: скажи, пожалуйста, а есть возможность потом эту обводку еще и перевернуть, и заголовок чтобы был снизу? (добавил картинку) только код текущий не изменяй, добавь новый

Comment: вот пример - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760365/Обводка-вокруг-контента/760730#760730. Увы но legend не поддерживает bottom    
 position